# How do these two modules differ in behavior

Tags: verilog

These two modules seem to be interchangeable. How does their behavior differ?

```
module Add_half (sum, c_out, a, b);
input a, b;
output reg c_out;
output reg sum;
always@(a, b)
begin
sum = a ^ b; 
c_out = a & b; 
end
endmodule

module Add_half (sum, c_out, a, b);
input a, b;
output c_out, sum;
assign sum = a ^ b; 
assign c_out = a & b; 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are subtle differences in event scheduling, which may result in different behavior at time 0.

When a or b are initialized to a certain non-X value at time zero, the always block may not see that as a change, and hence it may not be triggered. Consequently, the outputs may be inconsistent with the inputs.

In contrast, the outputs of continuous assignments will always be consistent with their inputs.